# Filtrar y agrupar filas que incluyen valores NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito hacer una consulta a una bd MySQL donde almacenos los datos q se registran diario de un contador:

BD contadores:

```
id_contador    contador_inicio     Contador_salida          fecha              maquina
       1             234                null          2020-04-12 09:02:09       prensa 1
       2             null               280           2020-04-12 17:02:09       prensa 1
       3             800               null           2020-04-17 09:10:09       prensa 1
       4             null                850          2020-04-17 17:00:00       prensa 1
```

Probé con:

```
SELECT * FROM contadores WHERE maquina = '$maquina' GROUP BY fecha;
```

pero necesito q me entregue algo asi:

```
   FECHA    CONTADOR INI   CONTADOR FINAL   MAQUINA
2020-04-12      234              280        PRENSA 1
2020-04-17      800              850        PRENSA 1
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal, alguna buena sugerencia.

Comment: ¿Y la primer consulta que resultado te dio?

Comment: hola , la primera me da asi:

Comment: SELECT fecha , SUM(contador_inicio), SUM(contador_salida) FROM contadores.... asumiendo que deseas la suma, pero no lo dices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ésta es una de las consultas que proporciona la salida que esperas:

```
SELECT DATE(fecha),
  MIN(contador_inicio) CONTADOR_INI,
  MAX(Contador_salida) CONTADOR_FINAL,
  UPPER(maquina) maquina
  FROM contadores
  WHERE maquina = 'prensa 1'
  GROUP BY DATE(fecha);
```

Para el dataset de pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE contadores(
  id_contador int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  contador_inicio int,
  Contador_salida int,     
  fecha datetime,
  maquina varchar(15)
  );
INSERT INTO contadores (contador_inicio, Contador_salida, fecha, maquina) VALUES
  ('234',NULL,'2020-04-12 09:02:09','prensa 1'),
  (NULL,'280','2020-04-12 17:02:09','prensa 1'),
  ('800',NULL,'2020-04-17 09:10:09','prensa 1'),
  (NULL,'850','2020-04-17 17:00:00','prensa 1');
```

Tu consulta no funcionaba porque estabas agrupando también por la hora, no únicamente por la fecha. De ahí que la función **`DATE()`** resuelva tu problema.

Sobre el diseño de tu tabla, no es necesario que guardes el contador en dos campos diferentes pues, con obtener el mínimo y máximo diario, ya consigues el inicio y la salida.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios y será un placer ampliar la respuesta.

Comment: veamos, lo reviso y te comento.

Comment: GENIAL, nada que decir, gracias Master David JP, era la solucion q me sacó el dia..gracias totales

Comment: Recuerda si te fue útil marcarla como aceptada

Comment: Yo solo añadiría que a tu agrupamiento le falta la columna de máquina

Comment: Pues había pensado en incluirla pero, como el OP utilizó un `WHERE`, supuse que consultaría cada máquina individualmente

Comment: Cuando tenga habilitados los votos nuevamente te daré tu +1 pues la considero útil

Answer (score 0):

- No podrías agrupar puesto que la fecha incluye tiempo y ese segmento no coincide en los 2 posibles grupos de salida.
- Lo que pudieras tratar es esa consulta pero filtrando para impedir que salgan los que tienen `NULL`
- Por otro lado dado que en la salida solo quieres la parte de fecha puedes sacarlo con la función **`date`** para que de esta forma la parte de tiempo sea deshechada, usando el alias que le diste en el `SELECT` ahora en la parte del `GROUP BY`
- Agrupa por las columnas que restan las cuales son **Fechas(este es el alias)** y máquina

Código

```
SELECT DATE(Fecha) Fechas,
       maquina,
       IF(contador_inicio IS NOT NULL, contador_inicio, 0) AS contador_inicio,
       IF(contador_salida IS NULL, MAX(contador_salida), 0) AS contador_salida
from contadores
GROUP BY Fechas, maquina;
```

Con un condicional extraemos los valores de contador inicio cuando no sean nulos

Para el caso de contador salida cambiamos la condición dentro del IF y establecemos que si el valor es nulo entonces extraemos el **`MAX`** de dicha columna

Comment: DEvuelve algo asi:
   FECHA    CONTADOR INI   CONTADOR FINAL   MAQUINA
2020-04-12      234                                                 PRENSA 1
2020-04-17      800                                                  PRENSA 1

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a tu pregunta la sentencia create de la tabla y datos de prueba para poder reproducir el caso @CarlosPatricioViera?

Comment: te refieres a como esta compuesta la tabla y los datos q tiene?

Comment: Ya no es necesario ya replique la tabla, si tengo respuesta edito y la agrego @CarlosPatricioViera :D

Comment: Disculpa @BetaM, no había visto tu respuesta... ¿Es posible que la web no me la hubiera mostrado hace media hora?

Comment: @DavidJP la había eliminado pero mi terquedad me hizo esperar para buscar alguna propuesta de valor al usuario